# Coding in R - Human Resources

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like below.

ID number is the person's ID, position is their job position, Dt_Alter is the date when they changed role and Education is their background.

I need to calculate their average time in position (until they get to the manager position) and also how many times they changed role until they get to manager.

Any tips I appreciate as I am new to `R` and having a hard time at this part of the analysis. The dataframe is huge.

```
ID Number        Position       Dt_Alter    Education
        2         MANAGER     2019-02-01    BUSINESS, MANAGEMENT AND ADMINISTRATION
        2     COORDINATOR     2019-01-01    BUSINESS, MANAGEMENT AND ADMINISTRATION
  2000261         MANAGER     2018-12-01    BUSINESS, MANAGEMENT AND ADMINISTRATION
  2000261      SUPERVISOR     2016-12-01    BUSINESS, MANAGEMENT AND ADMINISTRATION
  2000553         MANAGER     2018-12-01    ENGINEERING
  2000553     COORDINATOR     2016-04-01    ENGINEERING




structure(list(Matricula = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
Desc2 = c("GERENTE", "COORDENADOR SEGUROS", "COORDENADOR SEGUROS", "COORDENADOR SEGUROS", "COORDENADOR SEGUROS"), 
Dt_Alteracao = c("01/02/2019", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2018", "01/09/2017", "01/09/2016"), 
Education = c("BUSINESS, MANAGEMENT AND ADMINISTRATION", "BUSINESS, MANAGEMENT AND ADMINISTRATION", "BUSINESS, MANAGEMENT AND ADMINISTRATION",  "BUSINESS, MANAGEMENT AND ADMINISTRATION", "BUSINESS, MANAGEMENT AND ADMINISTRATION")), 
row.names = c("2.10823", "2.10824", "2.10825", "2.10826", "2.10827"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Would you please post a small sample of the data in a reproducible manner using dput()?

Comment: sure, but its too long to put it in here. How do I do in this case?

Comment: The dput function is useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Try something like `dput(head(df))`. If `head(df)` isn't sufficiently illustrative of the question, first extract another small dataframe which is adequately informative. Note that any such `dput()` would belong in the question rather than the comments.

Comment: woops, I have to put it in the question, hold on

Answer (score 1):

Below is my rough approach to this problem, using a combination of `ifelse` and `lag` functions. Basically, after ensuring you've ordered the file on ID.Number and date, the order of records should permit comparisons across records.  I made a flag for whether someone changed their position, and if true, computed the `difftime` across those records.

Hope this helps.

```
df$Matricula<-as.character(df$Matricula)
df$Dt_Alteracao<-strptime(df$Dt_Alteracao,format="%d/%m/%Y")
df<-df[order(df$Matricula, df$Dt_Alteracao), ]

# indicator for whether a position change occurred
df$changePos<-ifelse( df$Matricula== lag(df$Matricula,1) & df$Desc2 != lag(df$Desc2,1), 
                  "Changed Position", "Same")   # review this logic for a variety of row groupings

# measure weeks between positions
library(lubridate)
df$Dt_Alteracao2<-as.POSIXct(df$Dt_Alteracao)
df$time_in_pos<-ifelse(df$changePos=="Changed Position", 
                   difftime(lag(df$Dt_Alteracao2,1),df$Dt_Alteracao2,units ='weeks'),NA )
```

Comment: thanks Ben for your help ;) I've got an error message in the last code: In unclass(time1) - unclass(time2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Looks like you need to convert the date variable to `POSIXct` format. I updated the code above.
  Also, I assume your date format is day-month-YEAR.  Make sure that's specified correctly in your code.